# Check if a string contains at least five characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Am trying to check `string` contains at least five `characters` in `var1` . Am using `count` but it doesn't work as i expects.Meanwhile with the `var2`  it contains more than `five characters` from the `var1`.

```
var1 = "today news report"
var2 = "news report"


if var2.count(var1)  >=  5:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("nooooooo")
```

Your suggestions are welcome to achieve that.

Comment: What do you think [`var2.count(var1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20count#str.count) does? What value is it returning? Does that help you understand what's happening?

Comment: What would be the expected output when `var2 = 'nnnnn'` - there's only one unique character from `var2` but it does appear 5 times... does that count as a yes/no?

Comment: What would be the expected result in this case?, I mean what result you'd expect from the count?

Answer (score 5):

[`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) is searching for exact matches of `var1` a in `var2`. Instead you could use a [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), and see if the length of the intersection is greater than the threshold:

```
var1 = "today news report"
var2 = "news report"

if len(set(var1) & set(var2)) >=  5:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("nooooooo")
# yes
```

Comment: does this count for white space too? (it should not be right?)

Comment: Hard to tell from the question. Space is a character.

Comment: Well perhaps @Rebin. However it would be a matter of removing unwanted characters, i.e `len((set(var1) & set(var2)) - {' '})`. It is indeed hard to tell from the question however

Comment: Even the `set()` is speculation. The OP did not specify whether repetition counts or not.

Comment: Yes I agree @Tomalak. Just went for this answer but giving it a second check not sure which is the needed solution, guess I'll wait and have some feedback from OP

Answer (score 2):

if you want to see if `var2` contains 5 or more of the same characters found in `var1` you can use Python's `set` structure which has an [`set.intersection()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection) method. The `intersection()` method will convert what is passed into anoter set and return elements that are the same between the two.

```
var1 = "today news report"
var2 = "news report"

if len(set(var1).intersection(var2)) >= 5:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
# Yes
```

You can see that `set` gives you all the unique characters in `var1` and the `intersection` gives you only characters that are shared.

```
print(set(var1))
# {'d', ' ', 'w', 'n', 't', 's', 'r', 'y', 'o', 'a', 'e', 'p'}
print(set(var1).intersection(var2))
# {'r', 'n', 'p', 's', 'e', 'o', 'w', ' ', 't'}
```

The `&` operator can be used to get the intersection as well, so `set(var1).intersection(var2)` is equivalent to `set(var1) & set(var2)`.

Comment: Side note for the OP: `set(var1) & set(var2)` is syntactic sugar for `set(var1).intersection(var2)`, under the hood it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: Well, I just learned something! And it appears `set(var1) | set(var2)` gives you the union!

Comment: And `-` gives the difference. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use **count**:

```
var1 = "today news report"
var2 = "news report"


count = 0
for letter in set(var1):
    if letter != ' ': # Check if space
        count += (list(set(var2))).count(letter)

print("yes") if count >= 5 else print ("nooo")

#if count >= 5:
#    print ("yes")
#else:
#    print ("nooo")


#count = 8
```